# dynamic Kendogrid filterable

Tags: android-filterable

Is it possible to setup a custom filter for kendoGrid where values being entered wont behave as an auto-complete, but automatically filters as you type for string contains? like angular ng-show ?. Current behavior, you gotta select from a lookup or type a value and click filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone bumps into this one, here's my solution:

```js
          filterable: {
                          cell: {
                              inputWidth: 125,
                              showOperators: false,
                              template: function (args)
                              {
                                  $(args.element).bind("keyup change", function (e)
                                  {
                                     dtSource.filter({ field: "fistName", operator: "contains", value: args.element[0].value});
                                  });
                              }
                          }
                      }
```